# How can I search any Value in ArrayList via Binary Search

Tags: java, binary-search

I have a problem to get list including many index as a result of getting key value. I have an error in my code.

My City class shown below.

```
public class City implements Serializable{
    private String cityName;
    private String countryName;
    ...
}
```

My Arraylist contains city names and its country Names as shown below.

```
Shanghai, China
...
...
```

As Arraylist is very large size like 50000, I apply binary Search to search any character or word in the list.

I want to search any character or Word which is sensitive to Uppercase or lowercase and retrieve back their indexs.

How can I do this process?

The code run according to the defined characher, character string or  word shown below.

**Sample Examples**

```
Enter the word of character which I want to search : W
Enter the word of character which I want to search : Sha
Enter the word of character which I want to search : Shanghai
```

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the word of character which I want to search : ");
String charWord = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Search " + charWord);
Integer[] index = BinarySearch.binarySearch(cities, charWord);
System.out.println(index.toString());


public static Integer[] binarySearch( ArrayList<City> list, String key ) {
        Comparable comp = (Comparable)key;
        List<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer arr[] = null;
        int res = -1, min = 0, max = list.size() - 1, pos;
        while( ( min <= max ) && ( res == -1 ) ) {
            pos = (min + max) / 2;
            int comparison = comp.compareTo(key.contains(list.get(pos).getCityName()));
            if( comparison == 0) {
                res = pos;
                arrlist.add(res);
            }
            else if( comparison < 0)
                max = pos - 1;
            else
                min = pos + 1;
        }

        return arrlist.toArray(arr);
    }
```

Comment: what does this line : `comp.compareTo(key.contains(list.get(pos).getCityName()));` mean? are you looking for an exact match or some percentage of match like Shanghai and Shangall for e.g.? If the latter is the case you need to do a nearest match and you need to write a separate function to compare two strings and give you a measure of equality. `contains` only tells you if a string is present in another string. Also I believe a data structure like Ternary Search Trie would also be more efficient in that case.

Comment: @SomeDude I shared sample input. That's why I use contains method but it doesn't work.

Comment: *Enter the word of character which I want to search : W* : Does this mean that you want to get all Strings which start with `W` ? or contains `W` ? or ends with `W`? In any case it seems you are looking for something like prefix match in a set of strings for which a trie is more suited I believe.

Comment: @SomeDude contains W. Every city names starts with Upper letter. Therefore It gets city names starting with W. But I can use w(lower case) . It get city names containing w letter.

Comment: @SomeDude How can I rearrange this binary Code?

Comment: `contains W` ? binary search will not get you the right answer. The result may be anywhere in the list. `contains W` does not mean exactly as `starts with W`. It means `W` can appear anywhere in the string. In that case the problem is more complex than you think, and it takes time to compute that unless you do some preprocessing kind of stuff. If you mean cities that start with `W` or any given input then construct a trie and look for prefix matches. It should be fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search using city name

```
    private static class City {

        private String country;
        private String cityName;

        public City(String cityName, String country) {
            this.cityName = cityName;
            this.country = country;
        }

        public void setCityName(String cityName) {
            this.cityName = cityName;
        }

        public String getCityName() {
            return cityName;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return cityName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<City> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new City("Shanghai", "Shanghai"));
        list.add(new City("USA", "USA"));
        list.add(new City("China", "China"));
        list.add(new City("Germany", "Germany"));
        list.add(new City("China", "China"));
        list.add(new City("china", "china"));
        Integer[] indices = binarySearch(list, "China");
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(indices[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static Integer[] binarySearch(List<City> cities, Comparable key) {
        List<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int lo = 0, hi = cities.size() - 1, mid;
        cities.sort((str1, str2) -> str1.getCityName().compareTo(str2.getCityName()));
        System.out.println(cities);
        while (lo <= hi) {
            mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            int cmp = key.compareTo(cities.get(mid).getCityName());
            if (cmp == 0) {
                arrList.add(mid);
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else if (cmp < 0)
                hi = mid - 1;
            else
                lo = mid + 1;
        }
        return arrList.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }

    private static Integer[] searchByCharacters(Integer[] indices, List<City> list, String sub) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getCityName().contains(sub))
                result.add(i);
        }
        return result.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }
```

, output

```
[China, China, Germany, Shanghai, USA, china]
0 1
```

Comment: I edit my post. It works for not only words but also character or charater string.

Comment: Yes, any wrapper classes have Comparable, so `Character, Integer, etc`

Comment: @TonyBrand do you want to search over the characters in the city name also?

Comment: Exactly, This code works for both cases. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your City class justly only one value. My city class has two values cityName and country. I edited my post again.

Comment: I have added function for search by character

Comment: What if I can sort Integer values for cities List. How can I change this code? cities.sort((str1, str2) -> str1.getCityName().compareTo(str2.getCityName()));

Comment: what are the integer values for cities? you can change the comparison to any value you want, below compare with wrapper classes or any classes extends from `comparable` or any primitive data types using comparison operators `==, >, etc`

Comment: `cities.sort((city1, city2) -> city1.getIntegerVal().compareTo(city2.getIntegerVal()));`

Comment: Is it possible to apply binary Search in searchByCharacters method. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @TonyBrand you have to convert cityName to character array then sort them and apply binary search on the character array

Comment: private static Integer[] binarySearchByCharacters(List<City> list, char key) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            char[] chars = list.get(i).getCityName().toCharacterArray();
            Arrays.sort(chars);
            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(chars, key);
            if (index >= 0)
                result.add(i);
        }
        return result.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }

Comment: In this method, it is acceptable for only one letter because of defining char key. How can I convert it to string and this function runs the same as searchByCharacters method.

Comment: This function you wrote cannot be acceptable for more than one letter like "Sha"

Comment: How can I apply character String like Sha, Chi , owa in binarySearchByCharacters function?

Comment: @TonyBrand you need to get a string, then convert to `to char array` and sort them then apply binary search. and this operation over all strings that you have. but this operation is costly. This is if you want to apply binary search also over the characters

Comment: @TonyBrand `searchByCharacters` loop over the string and check if it contains this part or not. To ignore upper case and lower case you can use this `list.get(i).getCityName().toLowerCase().contains(sub.toLowerCase())`

Comment: However, binary search cannot be implement in searchByCharacters method.

Comment: I wanted to determine if searchByCharacters can use binary search. After your explaination, I understand that the usage of binary search in searchByCharacters  method is impossible. Thanks your reply.

Comment: @TonyBrand I have answer the question :)

Comment: I've done my project and uploaded my github repository. There is a problem for seaching part. When I write "Moscow", it shows 2 results without showing 1 result. Can you check my project if you don't mind. https://github.com/Rapter1990/Binary-Search-Example

Comment: sure, I will check it